# Why doesn't the Angular http.post method do anything after a certain number of successful runs?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-post

### Background

I'm developing an ionic angular android application. In one of the pages, the user can retrieve multiple pieces of data based on different codes they input.

I send a http request like this:

```js
console.log("Calling post...");
this.http.post<any>(
  `my-url`,
  {
    // data passed to the server
  },
  {
    headers: { /*  */ },
  }
)
.subscribe(
  (data) => { console.log("Received data!"); /* Do something with data */ },
  (error) => { console.error("An error happened: " + error); },
  () => { console.log("Finished..."); });
```

### Issue

For the first 5 runs, the code works and displays the correct data to the user, logging both "received data!" and "finished..." in the process. After that, I can only see the "calling post..." log in logcat, not even the `completed` callback runs.

Restarting the application seems to fix it for another 5 tries.

### What I've tried

- Searching the web for why an Angular http post request (or any web request) wouldn't run. The only answer I got is that unless I call subscribe (which I already do), it won't make a request.
- Checked the server logs: the server logs *every* request made to it. After the 5th try, it seems the requests aren't even sent.

Honestly, other than these I don't even have an idea why or how this could happen.

Comment: You have to make sure that all data send in the post and can you try to call this `api` from `postman` or try to test another `api` to make sure that your problem on the app or the backend end side.

Comment: For testing purposes, I would add a throttle between requests to see if you were packing too many requests back to back. Alternatively, I would make the calls synchronous just to see if that changes your results. I know there are certain limits on the number of http requests made, but i'm sure it is more than 5.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend that you try the execution of the service more than 5 times from a Postman or Imsomnia (light) apps to validate that the service responds according to how you expect. As they already told you, some backlends are usually configured with a limit of requests in a certain time.
2. Validate with the network of the tab in the Developer Tools of the Browser how the HTTP requests behave, the response you get and if these were hung or not.
3. Subscriptions with HTTP in Angular don't need to be unsubscribed because they self-destruct once finished:
   [image: https://angular.io/guide/http]